# SQL Get records from table where related objects dont met criteria

Tags: sql, join

```
SELECT  PRH.prid,  PRH.CreationDate, PRH.ClosedDate, PRA.creationdate
FROM PRHeader PRH
left join  PRAction PRA on PRH.PrId =  PRA.PrId
WHERE 
PRA.CreationDate =
(select min(CreationDate  )  from PRAction pa  WHERE  PRH.prid=pa.prid 
 and pa.ActionTypeId<>4)
```

OK I'm not sure how to explain this...
But I have one table PRHeader with objects
every object in PRHeader has 0-many related actions in PRAction.
The above code gets the earliest action for each object that has the relevant actiontype , because I want the timestamp from that one.
Problem is that some objects dont have any action that fits this criteria and then I still want the object returned but with null as the action time.
And obviously I only want each object once.
Any advice?

**Big thanks to Gordon Linoff!
That worked perfectly!**

Comment: You don't need to edit your question to notify readers that the problem has been solved. If one of the answers works for you the way you want, you can just [accept it formally](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work "How does accepting an answer work?"). Once you do that, there will be an immediately visible indication in the question list that your question has an accepted answer (= "is solved").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can move the `where` condition into the `from` clause, where you can `left outer join`.  One way is to just put the condition in the `on` clause:

```
SELECT  PRH.prid,  PRH.CreationDate, PRH.ClosedDate, PRA.creationdate
FROM PRHeader PRH left join 
     PRAction PRA
     on PRH.PrId = PRA.PrId and
        PRA.CreationDate = (select min(CreationDate)
                            from PRAction pa 
                            WHERE  PRH.prid = pa.prid and pa.ActionTypeId<>4
                           );
```

An alternative is to put this as a `join` condition:

```
select  PRH.prid,  PRH.CreationDate, PRH.ClosedDate, pa.creationdate
from PRHeader PRH left join
     (select prid, min(CreationDate)
      from PRAction pa 
      where pra.ActionTypeId <> 4
      group by prid
     ) pa
     on PRH.prid = pa.prid;
```

And, finally, if you don't want to do an aggregation, you can move the field calculation to the `select` clause:

```
select PRH.prid, PRH.CreationDate, PRH.ClosedDate,
       (select min(CreationDate)
        from PRAction pa 
        where  PRH.prid = pa.prid and pa.ActionTypeId <> 4
       ) as CreationDate
from PRHeader PRH;
```

Although this look like an aggregation, the engine should be able to use an index on `PRAction(prid, CreationDate)` directly.  You can make this more obvious (using MySQL syntax) by making the subquery:

```
       (select CreationDate
        from PRAction pa 
        where PRH.prid = pa.prid and pa.ActionTypeId <> 4
        order by CreationDate
        limit 1
       ) as CreationDate
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the left join in you question, but joining to a nested query. I think it would go like this:

```
SELECT PRH.prid, PRH.CreationDate, PRH.ClosedDate, PRA.creationdate
  FROM PRHeader PRH
  left outer join  (
       SELECT * 
         FROM PRAction pa
        WHERE pa.CreationDate = (
              SELECT min(pa2.CreationDate)
                FROM PRAction pa2
               WHERE pa.prid=pa2.prid 
                 AND pa2.ActionTypeId<>4)
             ) PRA on PRH.PrId =  PRA.PrId
```